# Stunnel as Windows service doesn't "start" on reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service, stunnel

Running stunnel 5.03 on Windows 2008 R2.

Everything is installed and working fine. I can even start/stop the service no problem...

When I reboot my server stunnel service shows as started but nothing gets logged and none of my connections work. Once i restart the service through service manager, everything works. So on startup it doesn't seem to run...

This only happens if i reboot the machine.

Output of my logs proving it works.

```
2014.09.11 15:57:48 LOG5[1612]: stunnel 5.03 on x86-pc-msvc-1500 platform
2014.09.11 15:57:48 LOG5[1612]: Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014
2014.09.11 15:57:48 LOG5[1612]: Threading:WIN32 Sockets:SELECT,IPv6 SSL:ENGINE,OCSP,FIPS
2014.09.11 15:57:48 LOG5[1612]: Reading configuration from file stunnel.conf
2014.09.11 15:57:48 LOG5[1612]: FIPS mode disabled
2014.09.11 15:57:49 LOG5[1612]: Configuration successful
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing is to make sure that the service is set to 'Automatic.'

Are there any events in EventViewer relating to the startup of this service post-reboot?